# How to set the interval of the x-axis in sns.factorplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, feature-selection

I'm using sns.factorplot to visualize the features importances ranking. Nine features was selected and they need to be ranked by how many iterations through before they were elimited by `SVM-RFE`.

[Figure like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpTz9.png)

```
meanplot = pd.DataFrame(list(r.items()), columns=['Features','Ranking'])
meanplot = meanplot.sort_values('Ranking', ascending=False)
sns.factorplot(x="Ranking", y="Features", data = meanplot[:9], kind="bar", size=4, aspect=3.1, palette='coolwarm')
```

The x-axis shows the iterations like `[0,2,4,8]`, but I want `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can refine the number of x-tick labels by first accessing the axis object returned by the `factorplot` and then providing a `step` size for the tick labels

```
ax = sns.factorplot(x="Ranking", y="Features", data = meanplot[:9], kind="bar", size=4, aspect=3.1, palette='coolwarm') 
ax.set_xticklabels(step=1)
```

Comment: Then it changed to [0,2,4,8,10]. When I set step to 2, it becomes [0,4,8]. Maybe the interval must be 2 at least.

Comment: @Salmon : unless you provide a runnable code with the data, it is hard to tell what exactly is going wrong